# How to get the continuous probability from SVM prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, roc

I have trained a binary SVM classifier and made predictions like the following:

```
classifier = svm(formula = type ~ .,
                 data = train,
                 type = 'C-classification',
                 kernel = 'polynomial')
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test[1:57])
```

The label that I am training against (`type`) is a factor. The prediction (`y_pred`) in this case is also a factor list. How can I obtain the probability/logits of these predictions so that I can produce a ROC curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, `probability = TRUE` need to be specified both when constructing the classifier and making predictions:

```
classifier = svm(formula = type ~ .,
                 data = train,
                 type = 'C-classification', 
                 probability=TRUE,
                 kernel = 'polynomial')
```

```
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test[1:57], probability=TRUE)
```

Then the `attr()` can be used to retrieve the probability scores:

```
prob = as.data.frame(attr(y_pred, "probabilities”))
```